# How to change background color of UIDatePicker set as UITextField inputView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

*Please do not mark as duplicate. The available answers haven't answered my issue.*

I am using a `UIDatePicker` as `UITextField's` `inputView` (inside a `UITableViewCell`):

```
@IBOutlet weak var theTextField: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.setValue(Colors.CI2, forKeyPath: "textColor")

        picker.datePickerMode = .date

        textField.inputView = picker
        textField.inputView?.backgroundColor = Colors.CI1 // my desired color

        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

}
```

The problem: The color does only change, once the picker is called a second time.

[image] [image]

I guess, that this issue occurs because the `inputView` is optional and only once the picker is called a second time, the `inputView` is instantiated at the moment where I want to change the color.

I have tried to subclass `UITextField` and observe `inputView`.

```
class DateTextField: UITextField {

    override var inputView: UIView? {

        didSet {

            self.inputView?.backgroundColor = Colors.CI1
            self.reloadInputViews()

        }

    }

}
```

Unfortunately without success. Same behavior. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: I have similar functionality in an app but I define the picker in `viewDidLoad` then just reference it later. Using this approach, the `backgroundColor` change works without issue for me. Also, your `didSet`will not get called until the `inputView` changes so that may also be contributing to your issues. Per Apple "willSet and didSet observers are not called when a property is first initialized. They are only called when the property’s value is set outside of an initialization context. "

Comment: The textField is part of a UITableViewCell. Therefore viewDidLoad will not take affect. Sorry, if that affects your answer anyhow

Comment: You should still be able to define it ahead of time, maybe not in `viewDidLoad` but in another place. Also, see the second part of my comment, I would not try to set the bg color in the `didSet`

Comment: i get your second part. but this solution is of the table anyways since it did not work. it was just a first guessed option

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: yeah. it was kinda yoda. i was saying, that i understand, that `didSet` is not the solution. it was just an attempt.

Comment: @DavidSeek Simply setting background color as `picker.backgroundColor = .blue` should work

Comment: Have you tried using @rmp's method with a cell resize? As in, when textfieldDidBeginEditing is called, you send a custom delegate/notificationcenter callback to your `UITableView` to resize that cell. and vice versa when closing it? It could be a rather fluid solution if done right, and would keep all your editing code inside of the cell class instead of outside of it like some other solutions.

Comment: @DavidSeek i used ur code as it is, it works fine. I kept textfield inside cell of static table view controller. did i missed anything..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake was that I had set the keyboard appearance in the Interface Builder. Once set back to `default` it worked like it was supposed to.

[image]

Comment: This is a great approach and it works BUT is there any way to change the background color AND have a keyboard appearance as dark?

Answer (score 3):

This code is working for me

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {   
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.datePickerMode = .date

        textField.inputView = picker
        textField.inputView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Even on the first edit it shows up blue.

Also:

Instead of creating a picker instance inside textField delegate method, you could create the picker in viewDidLoad method, set its background color, give it a tag and then access this picker using the tag in the delegate method instead of creating the variable there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following library for custom colours https://github.com/prolificinteractive/PIDatePicker

Answer (score 1):

create a function which holds the date picker colours, and call it in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. I think that should solve your issue.

Comment: and how will this be any different from the current approach?

Comment: The function would be called separately so you wouldn't need to wait until the value is changed to see a response.

Comment: if it is called as a function within 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' or directly inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` does not affect the lifecycle of am i wrong?

Comment: yes. as expected no change. since. as expected. if you set the value directly in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` or if you call a function at the same time -> the life cycle call happens at the same moment -> before the `inputView` is instatiated

Comment: thank you for your input. i have tried it your way, but it still needs a second load to change the color. tried it in the cellForRowAt, as well as awakeFromNib, as well as textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Answer (score 1):

So you mention that this text field is within a `UITableViewCell`... What I would suggest is adding the first block of code to a `UITextFieldDelegate` and then in the [`tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) function in the `UITableViewDelegate` , set the delegate of the text field to your custom `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Without knowledge of more of your code structure I can only provide you with a very generic implementation:

```
@IBOutlet weak var theTextField: UITextField!

//Add your customisation to the textField...
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

            let picker = UIDatePicker()
            picker.setValue(Colors.CI2, forKeyPath: "textColor")

            picker.datePickerMode = .date

            textField.inputView = picker
            textField.inputView?.backgroundColor = Colors.CI1 // my desired color

            picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    //Set the delegate when the UITableViewCell appears:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
                   forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dateCell = = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DateCell

        dateCell.delegate = self

        return dateCell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not change `inputView` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing()`. The last time you can change the `textField.inputView` property is in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()`.

As for the best practice: you should move all the code for the `textView.inputView` configuration to the place where you create the `textView` to do a *one time configuration*. For instance:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // get the cell
    // get your instance of textField
    // ...

    // Configure everything you want about your input view
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.setValue(Colors.CI2, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    picker.backgroundColor = Colors.CI1
    textField.inputView = picker // <-- You just have to assign this ONCE

    // ... Continue your setup ...
    return cell
}
```

If you need to change the configuration of the `inputView` *each time it has to appear* on screen, do the change of `textView.inputView = ...` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(){ ... }`.

---

#### Why it did not work

In your code (when you do the change in `textField DID BeginEditing`), the `UIDatePicker` shown was always the previously created one. It seems that the gray one was set (but not configured) when you created the `textField` instance.

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing()`, the system has already drawn the `textView.inputView` and **it will NOT** look again at the `inputView` property if you modify it.

Comment: thank you for your input. i have tried it your way, but it still needs a second load to change the color. tried it in the cellForRowAt, as well as awakeFromNib, as well as textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: I suspect you have instantiated a `UIDatePicker` somewhere without changing the color (that's why it is appearing gray at first).
It is most likely that you have done that, **otherwise the default keyboard** would show up **instead of the gray date picker**.

Please check with a few searches in your file: - where you set the `.inputView` property, - where you instantiate `UIDatePicker` elements in your code file.